# Why WebHost and WebHost Builder consider obsulte regard to generic host and generic host builder in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, webserver, hosting

Is there any special reason behind switching from **web host** and web host builder to **generic host** and generic host builder except its generality? What is the other benefit and why they always say that Web Host is only available for Backward Compatibility? Is it just matter of standard or there is other factors?
Thanks

Comment: Obsolete code is generally not well maintained if at all. They recommend the newer code because it is maintained. Eventually, most obsolete code is removed when the impact on the customer base falls below a threshold or when the security risks it imposes exceeds a threshold. You should not write any new code that uses components or interfaces that are marked as obsolete. Doing so carries undefined risks and potential impacts. Old code based on obsolete components may stop working at some point or fail to behave as expected. Some companies post policy on such matters.

Comment: Check migration notes here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model

Comment: Thanks. I follow the links and reach the following comparison:
https://andrewlock.net/avoiding-startup-service-injection-in-asp-net-core-3/
It seems there is problem with DI in the old one. But I should read it again to understand it. So it seems there is more than standardization.